# Wittgenstein and "linguistic trap"

Tags: logic, fallacies, wittgenstein, language

In a book on philosophy I've lost by now I encounter an argument about "linguistic trap" idea attributed to Wittgenstein, that is, such a trap is supposed to be "taking linguistic convention or linguistic representation of an object for properties of the object itself", a particular kind of confusion.

Now, obviously Wittgenstein proposed an idea of "language games", but from what I've read on the topic it's a rather different idea.

Have you encountered this idea and if you did, can you please point to the sources?

Comment: "*Philosophy is a battle against the bewitchment of our intelligence by means of our language*" (PI §109). The aim of philosophy is "*to show the fly the way out of the fly-bottle*" (PI §309). The idea is generally referred to semantic therapy, see e.g. [Later Wittgenstein's Anti-Philosophical Therapy](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/philosophy/article/later-wittgensteins-antiphilosophical-therapy/2EB061B08AC763962AB155111473EA97).

Comment: @Conifold. Great comment. I wonder why you don't post your comments as answers. I'd upvote this one. .  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is Wittgenstein's "The Big Typescript", pg. 415, or from the "philosophical Investigation, section 127. At least that's what I gather from the footnotes (46-48) [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=vbhlJUfx9MwC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=wittgenstein%201931%20linguistic%20trap&source=bl&ots=ni4KoBOxyR&sig=ACfU3U2jQ74oxGdVuDOpUVhA5ZM0Lsqi5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVnKTA5OHmAhVDVc0KHd0TAEUQ6AEwEXoECA4QAQ#v=onepage&q=wittgenstein%201931%20linguistic%20trap&f=false).

It might be helpful to consider the following citation-free quote given on [SEP's article on Wittgenstein](https://www.iep.utm.edu/wittgens/). I think it may be either a quote from one of his lectures or an excerpt from one of his posthumously published notebooks, but it goes as follows:

> Language sets everyone the same traps; it is an immense network of
>   easily accessible wrong turnings. And so we watch one man after
>   another walking down the same paths and we know in advance where he
>   will branch off, where walk straight on without noticing the side
>   turning, etc. etc. What I have to do then is erect signposts at all
>   the junctions where there are wrong turnings so as to help people past
>   the danger points.

The 'wrong turnings' here are precisely what you noted: taking a turn of language as an actual property of the material world.